# Eigenvalues of symmetric tridiagonal matrices with identical off diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

Is there a simple analytical solution to obtain eigenvalues (and eigenvectors) for this type of tridiagonal matrices ? ( Off diagonal elements are identical and the matrix is symmetric)

$ \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}-k & k & 0 & 0   \\\ 
k & a_{2}-2*k & k &  0 \\\
0 & k & -a_{2}-2*k & k  \\\ 
0 & 0 & k & -a_{1}-k
\end{pmatrix} $

To obtain eigenvalues of symmetric tridiagonal matrices, I used this formula $P_{k} (λ)=(α_{k}−λ)P_{k-1}(λ)−β^2_{k-1}P_{k-2}(λ)$. But I could not find simplifications.

Thanks for answer.